# Running multiple Python scripts in parallel using bash

Tags: python, windows, bash, winpty

I want to run a simple python script 100 times in parallel using bash. If I run the python scrips serial everthing is fine, but if I run them in parallel I get the error

stdin is not a tty
Presumably because the same python file gets opened multiple times?

Here's the bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}; do
        winpty python test.py &
done
```

If I remove the `&` sign everything works fine (serial) but not if I run it in parallel. The Python file is litterally just  `1+1`

PS: I run python with  `winpty python` and not the usual python because I run it from the git-bash console and that thing has issues... But again, I don't think this is where the issue comes from, because running everything in serial works fine...

Comment: winpty is expecting stdin to be a terminal, which is not the case when you run in the background, with `&`

Comment: @Philippe is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: If getting interactive output is not central to your usage scenario, probably get rid of `winpty`. Perhaps instead redirect output to a log file or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have winpty to test following script, but try :

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}; do
        winpty python test.py < /dev/tty > /dev/tty 2>&1 &
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work (output is tcsetattr failed. I now changed to ubuntu workflow, so issue is not relevant anymore